# node js. Sequelize transactions

Tags: javascript, node.js, transactions, sequelize.js

I have 'Banks' table with 'money' field in my database,

Users can withdraw money periodically, but they can withdraw only if there is money > 0 in the bank.

Firstly I should get the entity of bank, then check if(bank.money > amountToWithdraw) and then withdraw this amount.

Imagine the situation, when concurrent user try to withdraw some money.
In that moment when I check if(bank.money > amountToWithdraw) other user can perform withdraw operation and the real bank.money amount in the DB will be less.

How to apply transaction to finding bank operation(how to lock bank entity)?

```
models.sequelize.transaction(function (t) {

return models.Banks.findOne({where: {
    money: {
      $gt: 0
    }
  }).then(function(bank){

    //in this moment other user finished the same operation
// how to lock access for editing bank object by other users after //findOne method?

    bank.money -= amountToWithdraw;
    return bank.save({transaction: t});
  })
})
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use a lock on the row of the bank.

It can look something like this, depending on your database.

```
models.sequelize.transaction(function (t) {

return models.Banks.findOne({where: {
       money: {
         $gt: 0
       }
    }, lock: t.LOCK.UPDATE, transaction: t }).then(function(bank){

    bank.money -= amountToWithdraw;
    return bank.save({transaction: t});
  })
})
```

Comment: You cannot understand how much TIME I've spent looking for a good solution. I think that documentation is not very clear about transaction usage. Your question saved my life!

Comment: How to use two rows, for example in one row I have quantity 10 and in other 20, I want to reduce 3 and give to other, so that new quantities will be 7 and 23 ?

Comment: Hi @drinchev, I am trying to implement transaction but getting error TypeError: Sequelize.transaction is not a function

Comment: First, you need to create a sequelize instance then you are able to access the transaction method. @AjendraPrasad